# Как добавить флешку в загрузчик grub?

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

На компьютере стоит 2 ОС (Win 10, Linux) и появилась необходимость дополнительной ОС, но при условии, что она установлена на флешке (Linux/Debian 64). Каждый раз заходить в Boot-меню сильно накладно. Хотелось бы, чтобы в grub-меню, если вставлена флешка, появлялся дополнительный параметр с той ОС, которая установлена на флешке.

Это возможно?

Comment: вот [ответ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947409/is-there-a-way-to-boot-from-usb-through-grub-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Всё гениальное - просто.
Подключите флешку и загрузитесь в Linux-систему, которая установленную на диске.
Из под неё, обновите настройки grub2, командой: `sudo update-grub` и новый пункт появится в grub, при загрузке компьютера. Главное с этого момента старайтесь, не вытаскивать флешку из компьютера, это не критично, но есть возможность, что пункт в меню grub перестанет работать.